# JFrame and Rectangle

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paint

Can anyone tell me why the rectangle is not showing up on the frame?

I only see a button on the frame. Please help.

I tried to using the `paint` method for drawing the rectangle.

Should I use `paintComponent()` or just `paint()`?

```
public class GUI2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocation(500, 200);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        JButton button = new JButton("YO");
        panel.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new Action());
        frame.paint(null);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(250, 250, 200, 100);
    }

    static class Action implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You shouldn't have to explicitly call `paint`
2. get rid of the `paint` method
3. Make an Inner `JPanel` class
4. Yes override `paintComponent` in the `JPanel` class
5. Call `super.paintComponent` in the `paintComponent` method.
6. Add the class `JPanel` to the `JFrame`
7. Don't do everything inside the `main`, as you'll find out, that `static` will cause a problem for you. Do everything inside a constructor
8. Run the program from the EDT `SwingUtilitites.invokeLater()`.
9. Make the button a global variable so it can be accessed from the `ActionListener`
10. `setVisible` should be the last thing you do, after adding all the component.
11. When adding multiple components the `JFrame` you will want to use the `BorderLayout` positions, or set the layout to the `JFrame` to something else besides `BorderLayout`
12. Override `getPrefferedSize` in your `JPanel` when painting, so the `JPanel` has a respected preferred size.
13. Don't set the size of the `JFrame` just call `pack();`

---

Here is a refactor of your code

Also see [**Creating GUI with Swing**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) | [**Graphics2D**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) | [**Performing Custom Paintin**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for further details.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUI2 {

    JButton button = new JButton("YO");

    public GUI2() {
        button.addActionListener(new Action());
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
        frame.add(new DrawPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawRect(250, 250, 200, 100);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new GUI2();
            }
        });
    }

    static class Action implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Point the OP to a tutorial or two and win the giant teddy ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer the repetitiveness of these tasks is making me lazy. Thanks for the teddy to keep me motivated :)

Comment: Sometimes people have a difficulty of understanding English.
So, If you don't show some examples, it's hard to figure out the answer. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you why you'll get a `NullPointerException`

1. You've not overridden any paint method of any displayable component
2. You've not passed a valid `Graphics` context to you `paint` method, but I would discourage this any way
3. You should make use of the `@Override` annotation which would have prevented the class from compiling.  Use it when you think you're overriding a method of a parent class, it will tell you when you're wrong

Start by taking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and then take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about how painting is actually done in Swing

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example of your code:

```
   package test;

import javax.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator;

public class GUI2 extends JPanel{
    JButton button;
    JFrame frame;

    public GUI2() {
        button = new JButton("YO");
        //panel = new JPanel();
        frame = new JFrame();
        //panel = new JPanel();
        this.add(button);
        frame.add(this);
        //button.addActionListener(new Action());
        // this.paint(null);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocation(500, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawRect(250, 250, 200, 100);
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {

        GUI2 test = new GUI2();
    }
}
```

I have removed some statements but you can add them later

Comment: Thanks for a bad example. You've broken the paint chain by failing to call `super.paint`, it's not recommended to override `paint` of anything, you failed to take into consideration [initial threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and I would discourage anyone from initialising a frame from within side a component at the best of times.  IMHO, dropping a bunch of code on someone who is lacking in experience or understand is not a good way to teach them. They have no idea "why" you choose to do what you have done

Comment: Okay, My mistake I am also new to this website..I just wanted to help him

Comment: Thumbs up for wanting to help, no issue there, but the example is going to cause more problems for the OP then it will solve (IMHO)